# not receiving push notifications in cordova ios app using firebase

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, push-notification

Steps that I have done till now are as below :

1. Made provisioning profile,csr, fcm token,device registration also done.
2. Linked APN certificate with firebase account where my app is registered.
3. Enabled push notification from xcode.
4. Also tested push notification on https://pushtry.com/ it showed success. but still not receiving push notifications on my iphone.

I have done above all steps correctly but still not receiving push notification, I also tried sending notification through firebase panel but still was unsuccessful.

I have used cordova-plugin-firebase for generating fcm token and registering device to APN server.
I have created APN certificate .p12 file and also added that in FCM configuration panel.

please help where I am getting wrong??

Comment: i am using xcode 9.1 and my iphone is of OS11

Comment: I may be late to the party but maybe will help someone else. Try to disable and enable again the Push notifications from "Capabilities" in xCode. It's weird but that worked for me one time.